# Determining error for numerical integration of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

When determining absolute/local error of numerical integration schemes for, say, the solution to a system of ODE's, what does one use as their standard of comparison?  Is there one particular scheme that is generally regarded as reliable?

Comment: Do you mean the theoretical error order, the theoretical first term of the error expansion or practical error estimates? The usual "standard" are easy to solve differential equations like $y'=k·y$ or $y'=a·y·(1+x)^{-1}$.